# pygame, saving a image with low opacity

Tags: python, pygame

im making some images in my game and sometimes drawing colors with low opacity, but when i try to save it with;

```
pygame.image.save(the_img, the_name)
```

it's saves the image like i painted it with 255 opacity.
so how can i save a .png image that has colors with low opacity. [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxxZv.jpg) the blue color has 128 opacity (50%) but it's saves it like the opacity 255?
when i blit this image to my display it's shows it right but when i download it it's wrong??

Comment: Create a new transparent image then blit your image on it with half opacity. Then save the new image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image format must be one that supports an alpha channel (e.g. PNG):

```py
pygame.image.save(the_img, "my_image.png")
```

If you have a Surface with a color key ([`set_colorkey`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey)), you have to change the pixel format of the image including per pixel alphas with [`pygame.Surface.convert_alpha`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha):

```py
pygame.image.save(the_img.convert_alpha(), the_name)
```

If you have a surface with a global alpha value ([`set_alpha`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_alpha)), you need to `blit` the Surface on a transparent Surface (`pygame.SRCALPHA`) of the same size and store that transparent Surface (this also works for a Surface with a color key):

```py
the_img.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
the_img_alpha = pygame.Surface(the_img.get_size(), pygame.SRCALPHA)
the_img_alpha.blit(the_img, (0, 0))

pygame.image.save(the_img_alpha, the_name)
```

---

Minimla example:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

the_img = pygame.Surface((200, 200))
pygame.draw.circle(the_img, (255, 0, 0), (100, 100), 100)
the_img.set_alpha(127)

the_img.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
the_img_alpha = pygame.Surface(the_img.get_size(), pygame.SRCALPHA)
the_img_alpha.blit(the_img, (0, 0))
pygame.image.save(the_img_alpha, "the_img.png")

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    window_center = window.get_rect().center

    window.fill((127, 127, 127))
    window.blit(the_img, the_img.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```